How to join tables on columns where values are not exact?
Let's say I have two tables:



city
street_1




Toronto
123 Banana St


New York
69 Good Time Rd


Lost Angeles
420 Blaze It Dr


Dallas
888 Wonderful Line



And



street_2
fruit




123 Bannana St
Grapes


69 Good Tme Rd
Apple


420 Blaeze It Dr
Banana


888 Wonderaful Line
Pear



I want to join the above two tables on street_1 and street_2. How would I go about that since the values in both street_1 and street_2 are different? Levenshtein is out of question since it is going to take way too long.
Thanks

@iBeMeltin A table containing City, Street, and Fruit columns.

How does the Banana project (a fork of Kibana) related to this question? What does SSMS, and IDE (like) application have to do with it? Jsut because you can use use up to 5 tags doesn't mean you should spam them with unrelated technologies. Please [edit] your question to elaborate on how all those technologies are related (it only suggests (T-)SQL in the post), or remove the unrelated tags.

You can't There are things like SoundEx you can use to try, but they are generally bad at this and will not give satisfactory results. You'll need to find a way to get cleaner data.

@JoelCoehoorn Sorry, mate. My data is ducked.

Guess you're ducked then too, you might wanna play around with TRANSLATE function though, something like: where len(trim(translate(t1.col1, t2.col1, space(LEN(t2.col1)))) <= 1 and len(t1.col1) > 2 but this of course won't be perfect

Your main application should not even attempt this. Attempts at run time fuzzy matching will yield both false-positives and false negatives. Let the GIGO (garbage in garbage out) principle stand. (Only guarantee good output when given valid consistent input.) The task should then be to prevent the GI part of this by validating data in input. I know tat the USPS has an address lookup service that can be used for validating, correcting, and normalizing mailing addresses. I suspect that Canada Post may have a similar service.

Is this a matter of an exercise and theory or a business solution?

@T.S. Business solution.

If this is a business solution, you can create a single point address for your address consumers, give it an id and have your table look like addressId, fruit and addressId, city. In this case I believe city is just example.  Then you can join by address id while address data will be in the separate table.

If you need to make a JOIN on such data structure, your tables are wrong. You'll depend on user input correctness to make it work the way you expect, and we know user input is not reliable at all.
The proper fix is to normalize your database. Introduce a third table that will contain addresses, each with its own id. Your original tables won't contain the streets themselves, but only the id, which is internal to the system and not subject to user input. That way your street names are contained in a single place and you don't rely on both places being equal.
